# Program to prompt password

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to create this python program that will prompt the user to enter a password. However, the password has to be between 6 and 12 characters. Also it must have a "#" in it but not in the first character or last. This is what I have so far, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong I just keep getting the "Not a valid password" response. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank You

```
# This program will determine whether a password meets all security requirements
import re

print ("Hello, please enter a password between 6 and 12 characters.")
print ("The password may consist of a combination of numbers and letters, but the one of characters (after the first and before the last) must be a # sign.")
       
password = input("Please enter your password: ")
x = True
while x:
    if (len(password)<6 or len(password)>12):
        break
    elif not re.search("[a-z]", password):
        break
    elif not re.search("[0-9]", password):
        break
    elif not re.search("[A-Z]", password):
        break
    elif not re.search("[#]", password):
        break
    else:
        print("Valid Password")
        x = false
        break

if x:
    print("Not a valid password")
```

Comment: You are breaking out of the loop in every single case. You don't need `break` at all, since you are using the flag `x` to control the loop. You can use `continue` or `pass` for the first 5.

Comment: You also might consider using the Python `getpass` package to prompt for password input while hiding the characters themselves: https://docs.python.org/3/library/getpass.html

Comment: I guess you just didn't put valid passwords, funny enough. When I put a password as `toMe#rk1` it worked but the script will raise an error because of `x = false`. It needs to be `False`. After fixing that it works fine

Answer (score 0):

```py
# This program will determine whether a password meets all security requirements
import re

print ("Hello, please enter a password between 6 and 12 characters.")
print ("The password may consist of a combination of numbers and letters, but the one of characters (after the first and before the last) must be a # sign.")

is_valid = False
while not is_valid:
        password = input("Please enter your password: ")
        if (len(password)<6 or len(password)>12):
                print('Password is the wrong length')
                continue
        if not re.search("[a-z]", password):
                print('Password missing lowercase letter.')
                continue
        if not re.search("[0-9]", password):
                print('Password missing a number.')
                continue
        if not re.search("[A-Z]", password):
                print('Password missing uppercase letter.')
                continue
        if re.search("^#", password) or re.search("#$", password):
                print('Password cannot begin or end with #.')
                continue

        print("Valid Password")
        is_valid = True
```

I think this is roughly what you're trying to do, you can improve it to fit your use case.  The way you have your loop currently it will only ever run once, the break statement exits the loop if it hits one of your conditions. The `while` statement never gets a chance to check the `x` variable you set to false.

I modified the loop so it will repeatedly prompt until the password fits the format you specified.  You could also add a prompt to quit or try another password for a better user experience. I modified your `#` check so the regex checks if it is either at the beginning or the end of the password.

Also I changed all your conditions to `if` statements.  The order the conditions are checked is important, and could potentially hid a false condition.  Like the classic `FizzBuzz` problem.